# What do you do with the extra tables after you have normalised a database?

Tags: sql, database, normalization

I have normalised my database but now I have many extra tables. In principle are these still one table just split into smaller ones or do I need to name each one and are they independent of the last table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you normalize a relation you replace the original relation with new relations.  You don't have any "extra" tables.  Each of the new relations is fully fledged and needs a name.

Comment: So for example i have a table with repeating fields, i split the table in two so i now have CustID Name and CustID Hobbies. These are 2 different tables both with there own name?

Comment: @JoshuaHornby - I would say yes.  The question you need to ask yourself is how many names does a customer have and how many hobbies?  What is the main point of each relation?  When you are in the midst of grinding through the normalization process, you can lose track of the reality that you are modelling.  It helps to step back once in a while to think about how every table in your database will ultimately represent some object (whether tangible or intangible) or at the very least, an important linkage between objects.  When you look at things this way, table names seem more obvious.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you for helping. So last question, i had to create a ER model and logical model for the homework, so now i have more tables does this mean they will have to be re done? Or does it not matter and they can stay as they are?

Comment: @JoshuaHornby - I'm not sure what you mean by "ER model" as distinct from "logical model".  An ER diagram is a pictorial representation of a schema.  Your model could be "conceptual", "logical" or "physical", depending on how much detail you have and whether you have taken into consideration the way tables and columns will actually look in your database.  Whether what you've got can stay as it is now depends on whether you've made it to 3NF (or higher, if applicable) and what your instructor expects for the assignment.  Don't stop normalizing until you've reached at least 3NF.

Comment: When you say 'relation' you actually mean 'relvar'.

Answer (score 0):

If you did everything right your data are distributed over several full-fledged tables (with names :)).

Comment: oh I see, I should clarify what I mean by independent :)

Comment: Ah, @joel-brown just wrote a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

After normalizing you will get tables with less redundancy.
the tables witch you get after normalization it is dependent on each other.
but actually they are different you have to give name to each one.

conclusion : "You need to give name each one."